# Is \AfterEndPreamble really executing code after any \AtBeginDocument code?

Tags: languages, babel, etoolbox, hooks

The `babel` package loads the (last) language at begin document, thanks to an `\AtBeginDocument` command (lines 12.256 and 12.257 of its kernel):

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\bbl@main@language}}
```

On the other hand, the `\AfterEndPreamble` command from the `etoolbox` package is supposed to execute "code [...] at the very end of `\begin{document}`, after any `\AtBeginDocument` code."

But it seems not to be the case in the following MCE:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{babel}
%
\AfterEndPreamble{%
  \title{Quelle crise?}%
}
%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Indeed, if executed after the french language would be loaded, `\title{Quelle crise?}` should give a thin space before the "?" as it is the case in the following MCE:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{Quelle crise?}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: You sure that's the way it is documented? From the name I would have expected it to execute beforehand as it seems to do (can't check from here)

Comment: Yes, and page 4 of the documentation says more about all the steps 'inside' `\begin{document}` when `\AfterEndPreamble` is used. The command you have in mind is probably `\AtEndPreamble`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Babel`'s language `french` makes `?` active as shorthand. However it is done in `\begin{document}` in order to avoid disturbing the loading of other packages.
However, you have specified `\title` in the preamble *before* `\begin{document}`. It does not matter, that it is executed later. Only the time matters, when the code is *read* and translated to tokens.

Solution: You can enable shorthands temporarily in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{babel}
%
\shorthandon{?}
\AfterEndPreamble{%
  \title{Quelle crise?}%
}
\shorthandoff{?}
%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Without `\shorthandon{?}` the question mark has catcode 12 (other) and it is not treated as `babel` shorthand. With `\shorthandon{?}` the question mark is active (catcode 13) and is executed as shorthand at the time of `\maketitle`.
Thus you do not need `\AfterEndPreamble` here.