# French spacing disappears within commands

Tags: spacing, french

I am preparing a document in French, using the "babel" package with option "french" and using commands that include colons and semicolons. My problem is, the French spacing before colons and semicolons disappears when the commands are printed. I do not understand why, have not been able to find an answer. Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\newcommand\deuxpoints{Texte: texte}
\begin{document}
\deuxpoints\
\endgraf
Texte: texte
\end{document}
```

[image: The problem]

Comment: My guess is that when you define `\deuxpoints` the colon is not yet active. You can get what a space if you define `\deuxpoints` after `\begin{document}`

Comment: That is it. Very stupid of me not to have thought of that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, this is the main reason, IIRC, why the KOMA-Script manual suggests to use the `\title`, `\author`, etc. macros *after* the `\begin{document}`. To have any active characters in the arguments behave normally, as in the rest of the document.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed to in the previous comments, `babel` set the active characters `:!?;` only at `\begin{document}`, by using `\AtBeginDocument`.

One could keep the definition in the preamble by using the command 
    `\shorthandon{:}`
just before the definiion of `\deuxpoints` and `\shorthandff{:}` just after.

Another solution is to add the `KeepShorthandsActive` in the option passed to `babel`.

Surprisingly, the `etoolbox` hook `\AfterEndPreamble` would be supposed to fix the problem but does not directly work.

See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121496)

Comment: `\AfterEndPreamble` tokens will be executed when shorthands are not yet activated.